# Order is not updated to complete after a shipment is created in M1

Tags: magento-1

I am running a cronjob to create shipments.

**Method 1**, shipment is created but order is not updated to complete:

```
$shipmentItems = [];
$comment = '';
/* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

    $comment .= trim("{$item->getSku()}: {$item->getQtyOrdered()}\r\n");

    $shipmentItems[$item->getId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
}

Mage::helper('ffm_fulfillment/api')->log("With items {$comment}", Zend_Log::INFO);

$shipmentId = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->create(
    $order->getIncrementId(),
    $shipmentItems,
    $comment,
    false, // email
    false // include comment in email
);
```

**Method 2**: Shipment is created and order is updated to complete:

```
$itemQtys = [];$comment = '';
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
    if ($orderItem->getQtyToShip() && !$orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
        $comment .= trim("{$orderItem->getSku()}: {$orderItem->getQtyOrdered()}\r\n");
        $itemQtys[$orderItem->getId()] = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
    }
}
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQtys);
$shipment->register();
$shipment->addComment(
    $order->getIncrementId(),
    $itemQtys,
    $comment,
    false, // email
    false // include comment in email);
);
$order->setIsInProcess(true);
Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($shipment)
    ->addObject($order)
    ->save();
```

My question is , why by using **method 1** order is not updated to complete ?

Thank you

Comment: have you generated invoice too ? generating invoice is must to set order complete

Comment: yes, I have a paid invoice